# Filename not shown in Symfony 5.2 in form

Tags: forms, file-upload, symfony5

I am just learning Symfony and maybe I am doing something wrong.
I created a simple form with the possibilty to upload a file. After choosing the file the filename doesn't show up in the form.

**Screen 1  - Choose picture**

[image: Choosing Picture]

**Screen 2 - Filename isn't shown**
[image: No Display]

The picturename is correctly saved to the database, so it must be there :)

I used `->add('picture', FileType::class, ['required' => false])`

Can someone push me in the right direction. I am trying to figure this out for the last 2 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "bug" with that type of field in Symfony when using the Bootstrap form theme.

If you are using Symfony's Boostrap form theme

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml

twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig'
```

I would recommend adding some Javascript to fix this issue.

```
$('.custom-file-input').on('change', function(event) {
  let inputFile = event.currentTarget;
  $(inputFile).parent().find('.custom-file-label').html(inputFile.files[0].name);
});
```

Note that I'm using ES6 syntax here, for better compatibility with old browsers, you might want to use ES5 if you are not using a transpiler. Also, I using the `custom-file-label` class since I'm using Symfony's Bootstrap 4 form theme, you might want to adjust if you are using another theme.

`..files[0].name` is used since your FileType could accept multiple files.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added your JS-Code and it works :) To be honest this is going a little bit over my head since I have no JS experience at all.